# Is date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:options:) deprecated?

Tags: swift, calendar

In trying to work with the Calendar function `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:options:)` in a Playground, I get an error

> error: date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:options:) is unavailable:
>   use 
>   date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)
>   instead.

Yet the function is still listed in the docs.

Is that function deprecated?

### EDIT:

Looking more closely, it looks like that is a function of `NSCalendar`, but that function is not available in the equivalent Swift object, `Calendar`.

Is that really true? Calendar and NSCalendar are both available, but their interfaces offer functions with different parameters and behaviors? Ugh.

It appears that if you create a Swift 3 Calendar object, the equivalent function is `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`.

Comment: Just checked Dash and I don't see either listed as `deprecated`. I'd make sure I have `import Foundation` at the top of the playground.

Comment: Calendar is the Swift value type wrapper for NSCalendar (a struct, not a class), and those do not necessarily have the same interfaces. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md only states that *"These types will have the same functionality as their corresponding NS type."* and even that is not always true: NSLocale has a `displayName(forKey: value:)` method but Locale hasn't.